# Изменение данных в таблице mdb с помощью редактирования привязанного datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

На форме (c# winforms vs2010 net4.0) есть datagridview привязанный к файлу mdb (в файле mdb несколько таблиц, одна из которых имеет имя "Сотрудники": три колонки без поля id). Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить код ниже, чтобы работало добавление новой строки, удаление и изменение строки в datagridview с сохранением изменений в файле mdb?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

        private DataSet InitializeDataSet()
        {
            string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="c:\1.mdb";
            OleDbConnection conn = null;
            try
            {
                conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
                conn.Open();
                DataTable schemaTable;
                schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
                OleDbCommand cmd;
                OleDbDataReader dr;
                for (int i = 0; i < schemaTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    String strTable = schemaTable.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + strTable, conn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    ds.Tables.Add(strTable);
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + strTable, conn);
                    da.Fill(ds, strTable);
                }
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return ds;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataSet ds = InitializeDataSet();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bindingSource1.DataSource = ds.Tables["СОТРУДНИКИ"];
            dGVpeoples.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        }

        private void btnSaveP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                bindingSource1.EndEdit();
                //da.Update(ds.Tables["СОТРУДНИКИ"]); ????
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);
            }
        }

        private void btnNewP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //ds.Tables["СОТРУДНИКИ"]   ??? добавить новую строку и перейти к ней для заполнения
                bindingSource1.MoveLast();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);
            }
        }

        private void btnCancelP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);
        }

        private void btnEditP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //???
        }

        private void btnDelP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Вы хотите удалить эту строку?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                bindingSource1.RemoveCurrent();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Собственно, нужно использовать метод [DataAdapte.Update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.update?view=netframework-4.8). См. [Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters)

Comment: В методе `InitializeDataSet` у вас не используются `OleDbCommand cmd` и `OleDbDataReader dr` - можете их выкинуть из кода.